# How to use import instead of require with node js?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

**Goal:** To be able to use es6 import, export default, etc...

What I have done is include a `.babelrc` file in the root of my project which contains:

```
 {
   "presets": ["env", "react", "stage-0", "stage-1"],
   "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
 }
```

I looked at the docs on babel and for node it said that all I would have to do is include the preset `"env"` which I do, but when I try to do an statement like:

`import { data } from './data'`

I get an unexpected token error on the import statement, so I assume I am not doing something correctly.

Comment: Have you installed the preset?

Comment: Yes everything is installed, just getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

Comment: You verified that the transpiled files and not the original files are loaded?

Comment: Are you actually compiling the files with Babel somehow? The config is fine but you haven't told us how you're actually running Babel.

Comment: @loganfsmyth,
Oh this is probably the step I'm missing, from what I looked at the babel that is all I saw to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical webpack.config.js

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            use: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I suggest you update .babelrc to the following.

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
          "env",
          {
            "modules": false,
            "loose": true
          }
        ],
        "react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

for more goodies decorators / function binding / class props etc,

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
          "env",
          {
            "modules": false,
            "loose": true
          }
        ],
        "react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-object-rest-spread",
        "transform-function-bind",
        "transform-class-properties",
        "transform-decorators-legacy",
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did not fix it, am I totally forgetting a step somewhere or something?

Comment: try clearing out node_modules `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install`. Then run  your webpack config. Check your webpack config as well. I'll update my answer to include webpack config referencing js config.